# Nested structured array field access with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am working on parsing Matlab structured arrays in Python. For simplicity, the data structure ultimately consists of 3 fields, say header, body, trailer. Creating some data in Matlab for example:

```
header_data = {100, 100, 100};
body_data = {1234, 100, 4321};
trailer_data = {1001, 1001, 1001};
data = struct('header', header_data, 'body', body_data, 'trailer', trailer_data);
```

yields a 1x3 struct array.

This data is then read in Python as follows:

```
import scipy.io as sio
import numpy as np

matlab_data = sio.loadmat('data.mat', squeeze_me=True)
data = matlab['data']
```

This makes `data` a 1-dimensional `numpy.ndarray` of size 3 with `dtype=dtype([('header', 'O'), ('body', 'O'), ('trailer', 'O')])`, which I can happily iterate through using `numpy.nditer` and extract and parse the data from each struct.

The problem I'm trying to overcome is that unfortunately (and out of my control) in some of the files I need to parse, the above defined struct arrays are themselves a member of another struct array with a field `msg`. Continuing with my example in Matlab:

```
messages = struct('msg', {data(1), data(2), data(3)});
```

When this is loaded with `scipy.loadmat` in Python, it results in a 1-dimensional `numpy.ndarray` of size 3 with `dtype=dtype([('msg', 'O')])`. In order to reuse the same function for parsing the data fields, I'd need to have logic to detect the `msg` field, if it exists, and then extract each `numpy.void` from there before calling the function to parse the individual header, body and trailer fields.

In Matlab, this is easily overcome because the original 1x3 struct array with three fields can be extracted from the 1x3 struct array with the single `msg` field by doing: `[messages.msg]`, which yields a 1x3 struct array with the header, body and trailer fields. If I try to translate this to numpy, the following command gives me a view of the original `numpy.ndarray`, which is not a structure (`dtype=dtype('O')`).

I'm trying to figure out if there an analogous way with `numpy` to recover the struct array with three fields from the one with the single `msg` field, as I can do in Matlab, or if I truly need to iterate over each value and manually extract it from the `msg` field before using a common parsing function. Again, the format of the Matlab input files is out of my control and I cannot change them; and my example here is only trivial compared to the number of nested fields I need to extract from the Matlab data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to recreate your file with Octave (save with -v7), I get, in an Ipython session:

```
In [190]: data = io.loadmat('test.mat')
In [191]: data
Out[191]: 
{'__globals__': [],
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, written by Octave 4.0.0, 2016-10-04 20:54:53 UTC',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 'body_data': array([[array([[ 1234.]]), array([[ 100.]]), array([[ 4321.]])]], dtype=object),
 'data': array([[([[100.0]], [[1234.0]], [[1001.0]]),
         ([[100.0]], [[100.0]], [[1001.0]]),
         ([[100.0]], [[4321.0]], [[1001.0]])]], 
       dtype=[('header', 'O'), ('body', 'O'), ('trailer', 'O')]),
 'header_data': array([[array([[ 100.]]), array([[ 100.]]), array([[ 100.]])]], dtype=object),
 'messages': array([[([[(array([[ 100.]]), array([[ 1234.]]), array([[ 1001.]]))]],),
         ([[(array([[ 100.]]), array([[ 100.]]), array([[ 1001.]]))]],),
         ([[(array([[ 100.]]), array([[ 4321.]]), array([[ 1001.]]))]],)]], 
       dtype=[('msg', 'O')]),
 'trailer_data': array([[array([[ 1001.]]), array([[ 1001.]]), array([[ 1001.]])]], dtype=object)}
```

`body_data`, `header_data`, `trailer_data` are Octave cells, which in `numpy` are 2d objects arrays containing 2d elements

```
In [194]: data['trailer_data'][0,0]
Out[194]: array([[ 1001.]])
In [195]: data['trailer_data'][0,0][0,0]
Out[195]: 1001.0
```

`data` is a structured array (1,3) with 3 fields;

```
In [198]: data['data']['header'][0,0][0,0]
Out[198]: 100.0
```

`messages` is (1,3) with 1 field, with further nesting as with `data`.

```
In [208]: data['messages']['msg'][0,0]['header'][0,0][0,0]
Out[208]: 100.0
```

(This may be a repetition of what you describe, but I just want to clear about the data structure).

================

Playing around, I found that, can I strip out the `(1,3)` shape of `msg`, with indexing and concatenate:

```
In [241]: np.concatenate(data['messages']['msg'][0])
Out[241]: 
array([[([[100.0]], [[1234.0]], [[1001.0]])],
       [([[100.0]], [[100.0]], [[1001.0]])],
       [([[100.0]], [[4321.0]], [[1001.0]])]], 
      dtype=[('header', 'O'), ('body', 'O'), ('trailer', 'O')])
In [242]: data['data']
Out[242]: 
array([[([[100.0]], [[1234.0]], [[1001.0]]),
        ([[100.0]], [[100.0]], [[1001.0]]),
        ([[100.0]], [[4321.0]], [[1001.0]])]], 
      dtype=[('header', 'O'), ('body', 'O'), ('trailer', 'O')])
```

this looks the same as `data`.

For some reason I have to reduce it to a (3,)` array before the concatenate does what I want.  I haven't wrapped my mind around those details.

Comment: It looks like that will work. I had tried loading the Matlab data with `squeeze_me=True` because I was able to extract the values using `[()]` which seemed more trivial than `[0,0]`, as they were no longer stored as 1x1 arrays, but all that's all it got me.